# How to Refresh the (indexes) azure search service, recently uploaded file in Blob container without using cron job

Tags: python, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-cognitive-search, azure-rest-api

I have created azure storage account and blob container and also created azure search service added blob container in this search service so when i upload new document to the blob i need to refresh the indexer through the REST API call using python please give me a suggestion is there API to refresh the indexer.

Comment: You mean refresh the data in index, right?

Comment: NO refresh the indexer or how to run the indexer through a script we can set the cron job but it will take more cost istead of we can run the indexer or we can create index right ?

Comment: if i have uploaded 5 docs previously so indexer is showing total 5 docs and now i'm uploading 1 more doc so indexes it should show total 6 doc ?so i need to run the indexer again?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer#indexer-schedule to add an indexer schedule so it runs periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An indexer can have a schedule, so the indexer will automatically run periodically and index new or changed blobs. Take a look at [indexing blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage).

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

The indexer can be run manually via the REST interface. You can trigger it through your own application or use something like a Logic or Function app with a storage trigger.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/run-indexer

Comment: run indexer we can schedule by our requirements ,but if i need to run manually through a program how it is possible